# Increase access token validity

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Is it possible to generate an access token to read the feed of a facebook account, where the access token never expires.

From what I understand 60 days is the maximum if the initial login access token is exchanged.

Is it possible to go longer than 60 days?

Comment: Explain *facebook account*

Comment: No, it's not possible to get User Access Tokens which are valid for longer than 60 days...

Answer (score 0):

Now that *offline_access* is no longer provided, the answer is **NO**.

There used be a permission called *offline_access* that let access token works longer for period of time, but [it is removed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal/) now. [Short-term access token and long-term access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#termtokens) are introduced, instead.

When you redirect your potential user to Login Dialog and the user complete his login and app authorization process, user is redirected back to your web page. That's where you get *code* parameter and you will exchange it for *short-term access token*, which stays valid for about 2 hours. That should be enough for login purpose.

If you wish to store the token for later use you should acquire *long-term access token*. I believe this is the one you mentioned. This token lives up to about **60 days** as you already figured out and it is the longest.